How can I pass input to an R script being run with nohup?
I am currently running R code on a server in the background with nohup in the following way:
nohup R --no-save < Rscriptname.R &> out &
I need to make some small changes to the script each time I run it. I was updating the script locally and then re-uploading it to the server before running it again, but I decided to add some readline() commands to take input for the variables that I need the change. My problem is I have no idea how to input the values as the above command does not trigger the prompts to show up since I am not actually opening an R session on the command line. Is there a way to pass the values I want to pass to the readline commands when running the command initially? I believe they can somehow be added after the filename, but I am unsure of what the syntax would be.
Alternative solutions are also welcome. I only have two values that I need to pass, so I could continue just updating the script and running it again, but I'd like to save some time.
I tried running the command with the updated script, but it did not prompt me for the readline() inputs.

Rather than using readline, you can pass command line arguments. You can access them via the commandArgs() function in R. It would probably also be easier to use Rscript to actually run the script.

with mkfifo(1) create a pipe, from CLI you can echo commands (or whatever) to that pipe and your script can read those commands from it

I would probably create a separate json or yaml file of parameters that the script reads from and update those.
